# backup of mysql individual databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a so many of databases all running from my local WAMPserver and have found that the command below runs well but has a problem with the databases that have spaced in their names, all other databases export with no problems its just the ones with spaces that display the error

the code I am using is below:-

```
mysql.exe -uroot -p1234 -s -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" | for /F "usebackq" %%D in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"`) do mysqldump %%D -uroot -p1234 > S:\Backup\MySQL\%%D.sql
```

The error I keep getting is on my database called "example data":-

mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'example' when selecting the data base

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you manually exporting database which has space in it's name  from phpmyadmin is it firing same error ?

Comment: no, its exporting fine from phpmyadmin, and when I dump all databases in to one file, there is no error, its just when I am trying to do on an individual basis